# How do I write a palindrome check?

Tags: ruby

I'm currently going through some programs to learn Ruby. I've been playing around with a palindrome program for a bit, though no matter the input (a palindrome) I end up on `else`.

Here is some of the code I've been trying:

```
print "enter a string:\n"
string = gets
if string.reverse == string 
  print "it's a palindrome"
else 
  print "not a palindrome.\n"
end
```

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newline character is not being deleted from the string.  Try this code:

```
print "enter a string:\n"
string = gets.chomp
    if string.reverse == string 
        print "it's a palindrome"
    else 
        print "not a palindrome.\n"
    end
```

Here is some more explanation:

```
>> string = gets
racecar # input string
=> "racecar\n"
>> "racecar\n" == "racecar\n".reverse # "racecar\n" is not a palindrome with newline character
=> false
>> string = gets.chomp # chomp method deletes newline character
racecar
=> "racecar"
>> "racecar" == "racecar".reverse # "racecar" without a newline character is a palindrome
=> true
```

Comment: Maybe `if string.reverse.downcase == string.downcase`?

Answer (score 1):

Learn how Ruby's [`puts`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-puts) works: It's like [`print`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-print), only smarter.

If a string ends with `"\n"`, it prints it as is. If it doesn't end with `"\n"`, it prints the line and adds `"\n"`. Either way, you're guaranteed to have new-line added.

Knowing that, consider this:

```
puts "enter a string:"
string = gets
if string.reverse == string 
  puts "it's a palindrome"
else 
  puts "not a palindrome."
end
```

As a result, no new-lines need to be added to the strings. `puts` is the standard method for outputting lines to files and the console in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

The following statement will return true if it's a palindrome and false otherwise:

`string == string.reverse`